# In-app billing of sample application is failing with payment error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Executed the following steps for running the sample application, but the application is failing with payment error.

1. Downloaded the sample application from android SDK
2. Added Google Play public key to the sample application code.
3. Changed the package name of the sample application.
4. Built the sample application in release mode and sign it.
5. Created a product list for the sample application.
6. Published the items of product list (sword_001 and potion_001) for the draft version of sample application.
7. Test account registered under the Google Play publisher account.
8. Verified that device is running a supported version of the Google Play application.
9. Installed the same signed application onto the device.
   10.My test account is the primary account on my device.
   11.Ran the application and purchased the sword.

When I try to do a purchase getting the following error while the order is being authorized ('authorize payment' is displayed), this usually happens about 30 seconds after the order has been placed (i.e. 'accept & buy' has been tapped).

**"Your payment could not be processed. sign in to your google wallet account to request support"**

Does anyone experiencing the same error ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got fixed when I changed the API version number inside makeRequestBundle() method of BillingService.Java:

request.putInt(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION, 1);

to

request.putInt(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION, 2);

Answer (score 0):

Getting in-app billing is challenging. Its not easy to read thru and get it integrated. I have a project created which works like a hello world, I suggest you download and use that. There are just too many variables. I have documented the integration steps [here](http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/integrate-in-app-billing-just-3-lines-of-code-in-your-app/).

Comment: Trust me, there are many causes. From signing in, to incorrect card to incorrectly configured google play account. Anything can be wrong. This piece of android sdk is complex to understand and debug. You are better off trying a hello world with my download and going from there. This is a rare occasion when I dont give specific advice, but a download to help debug.

Comment: your link is blocked in my network. Can you provide another source for the sample example ?

Comment: I just tried it. It works for me. You will have to try a different network, nothing much I can do at this time.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for your time!